# How to create URL to browse an artifact in NEXUS repository?

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I want to generate a URL to browse directly to any artifact.

I can browse a specific repository with the following url.
https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#view-repositories;maven-sites~browsestorage

Is it possible to browse a specific item with a single URL?
e.g. in the above repository there is an artifact called nexus-oss/css.
I would like to have a URL that will directly expand the tree in the browsestorage view to the artifact nexus-oss/css.

Thx
derek

Answer (score 1):

You can browse to it directly, but afaik not using the Nexus UI.
For example:
https://repository.sonatype.org/content/sites/maven-sites/nexus-oss/css/

If there was a url to do this, I reckon it would look like this:
https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#view-repositories;maven-sites~browsestorage~/nexus-oss/css/maven-base.css
 Since this is the url you get when you select a specific artifact and click its "Contained In Repositories" link.